# How can I get this error message sent back to the original page in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

**index.php:**

Form is within a Bootstrap modal.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="core/login.php" method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

**core/login.php:**

```
if($conn){
  ...
  if ($count > 0) { 

    ...

  }
  else { echo "Login Failed"; }

  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);
}
```

How can I get the echo sent back to the same Bootstrap modal as the login form at `index.php`?

Comment: simple way to show the error is ..call all code of login.php in index.php...like:- use if(isset($_POST)){ ** HERE is your CODE**}

Comment: you may append the error to the url index.php?error=xyz and then on the index page print the value of error if it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($conn){
  ...
  if ($count > 0) { 

    ...

  }
  else {
   header("Location: index.php?error=loginauth");
   exit;
 }

  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);
}
```

Then in index.php you can get back the error parameter and switch it:

index.php

```
<?
  if(isset($_GET['error']))
{
   if($_GET['error']=='loginauth')
  {
    echo "Login failed";
  }
   if($_GET['error']=='error2')
  {
    echo "error 2 description";
  }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax in your modal. `jQuery.ajax();`

Plunker example http://embed.plnkr.co/ThNNWFlvbnG6qFwrSd97/preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you provide an example on how to use it in my situation?

Comment: please improve your answer with an example

Comment: Ok, I'll make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Didar_Uranov Sorry I still don't understand. I see what you're doing but I don't understand where this should all fit in to my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Post the data using jquery .ajax() or .post()

First you have to get your data from the form with jquery:

```
var form_values = { 
                    value_name1 : $('#selector1').val(),
                    value_name2 : $('#selector2').val()
                  };
```

Then send the data to the processing php script using [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and the php script should return the validation message in json format with json_encode:

```
$.post('/url/path', form_values, callback(data));
```

The callback() function will hold your code what happens after the post call is completed, either failed with a error or success:

```
function callback(data)
{
   //Decode received message with JSON.parse if it is available or $.parseJSON if not
   data = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);

   //Check message variable received from php
   if (data.message == "Login Failed")
   {
       //Do whatever you want here, I`ve used alert to be simpler
       alert('Failed to login');
   } else {
       alert('Succesfully logged in');
   }
}
```